# Fully-convolutional ResNets using TF-Slim run very slow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm porting the code that does pixel labeling (FCN-style) originally implemented in Caffe to TensorFlow. I use Slim's implementation of ResNets (ResNet-101) with stride of 16px and further upsample it with up-convolutional layer to achieve the final stride of 8px. I have batch_size=1 as the input images are of arbitrary size. The problem is that training is really slow. It processes 100 images in about 3.5 minutes, while my original caffe implementation does it in 30secs on the same hardware (Tesla K40m). Here's the reduced version of the code I have:

```py
import datetime as dt

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
from tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets import resnet_v1

from MyDataset import MyDataset
from TrainParams import TrainParams

dataset = MyDataset()
train_param = TrainParams()

#tf.device('/gpu:0')

num_classes = 15

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, None, None, 3])

with slim.arg_scope(resnet_v1.resnet_arg_scope(False)):
    mean = tf.constant([123.68, 116.779, 103.939],
                       dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 1, 1, 3], name='img_mean')
    im_centered = inputs - mean
    net, end_points = resnet_v1.resnet_v1_101(im_centered,
                                              global_pool=False, output_stride=16)

    pred_upconv = slim.conv2d_transpose(net, num_classes,
                                        kernel_size = [3, 3],
                                        stride = 2,
                                        padding='SAME')

    targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, None, None, num_classes])

    loss = slim.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(pred_upconv, targets)


log_dir = 'logs/'

variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(include=["resnet_v1"])
restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)

with tf.Session() as sess:

  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  sess.run(tf.initialize_local_variables())

  restorer.restore(sess, '/path/to/ResNet-101.ckpt')

  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=.001)
  train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)
  t1 = dt.datetime.now()
  for it in range(10000):
      n1=dt.datetime.now()
      batch = dataset.next_batch() # my function that prepares training batch
      sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={inputs: batch['inputs'],
                                      targets: batch['targets']})
      n2=dt.datetime.now()
      time = (n2-n1).microseconds/(1000)
      print("iteration ", it, "time", time)
```

I'm only learning the framework, and I only put together this code in couple of days, so I understand it may not be the nicest. As you can see, I also try to measure the actual time it takes for data preparing code and forward-backward passes of the network. And this time is actually much smaller when summed up for 100 iterations, only 50sec compared to the real runtime. I suspect there can be some thread/process synchronization going on, that's not measured, but I find it quite strange. top command shows about 10 processes titled the same as the primary one that were perhaps spawned by it. I also receive warnings like so:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:245] PoolAllocator: After 1692 get requests, put_count=1316 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.759878 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.87234
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:257] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110
```

Could you perhaps point me in a right direction on how I can speed this up?

Thanks.

UPDATE. After more research I found that 'feeding' data can be slow compared to queues, so I re-implemented the code with the queue in a separate thread: https://gist.github.com/eldar/0ecc058670be340b92e5a1044dc8a089 but the runtime is still about the same.

UPDATE2. Looks like I figured what the issue with the speed is. I train fully-convolutionally, and my images are of arbitrary sizes and aspect ratios. If I feed dummy random numpy tensors of fixed size, it works fast. If generate input tensors of 10 predefined sizes, the first 10 iterations are slow, but then it speeds up. Looks like in TensorFlow the resizing of all tensors at each iteration is not as efficient as in Caffe. I will file a ticket on the project's GitHub.

Comment: Please keep in mind that it's a freaking huge model. The "101" in the resnet_v1_101 is from the fact that it's 101 conv layers deep.

Comment: not sure if what you get is expected though

Comment: afaik they use several different machines to train it

Comment: I'm only fine-tuning the model pre-trained on ImageNet to my data. I implemented the same pipeline in Caffe before, and it works literally 10x faster per training iteration on exactly the same data.  Something must be wrong.

Comment: @SimpleMan Which pre-trained version of ResNet-101 are you using? I need to do something similar, can you provide a link to your .ckpt file for ResNet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was due to input images of arbitrary size. TensorFlow has something which is called auto-tuning, so at run-time they profile various algorithms for each particular input size, and decide which is best. In my case this was happening at each iteration.

The solution was setting the environment variable `TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0`:

```
export TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0
python myscript.py
```

More at this Github ticket: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5048

Comment: Code from linked issue: https://gist.github.com/eldar/0ecc058670be340b92e5a1044dc8a089

Answer (score 2):

In general, a TensorFlow resnet implementation should not be (much) slower than in caffe. I just compared the implementation in caffe/barrista (https://github.com/classner/barrista/tree/master/examples/residual-nets) and the example in Tensorflow (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/resnet) and they run up to a negligible difference over the full training at the same speed.

I did have trouble with the Tensorflow implementation first, which brought me to this page. The reason was, that the version from github that I built was not stable and was due to intermediate development code very slow. A `git pull` and recompile solved the problem.

If you are re-implementing for yourself, however, note how the BatchNorm update ops are triggered. In the tensorflow example, this is done in `resnet_model.py`, l. 172. They are added directly to the 'fetches' of the `run` operation and hence executed in parallel and ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I also used the nightly build, because support for ResNets was not in the stable release. Which version did you use? Also, did you use a dataset of your own, and in this case how did you load the data? I suspect my data loading code may not be optimal.

Comment: So I updated to 0.11.0rc0 version, and I can see that there is no 10 other python processes running simultaneously, which is a good sign, but it is still just as slow.