# Find compute bottleneck

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Resnet based network and it really slow
It use 2 minutes to run one image

Here is what I did that tried to find bottleneck

I tried to use [timeline](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659) to find compute bottleneck
But `chrome://tracing` show nothing.(the only change is `^_^`=>`filename`)

The timeline file has value, file size is 885.9MB

```
    { # for example
        "name": "map/while/LoopCond",
        "pid": 1,
        "ts": 1487341119596183,
        "cat": "DataFlow",
        "tid": 0,
        "ph": "t",
        "id": 31618
    },
```

When I saving the timeline file, console show below message, does it important?

```
tcmalloc: large alloc 1233903616 bytes == 0x7fa896f76000 @  0x7faad02b78bf 0x7faacff0b175 0x7faacff0b490 0x7faacff36328 0x7faacfed2dc3 0x7faacff846c7 0x7faacff86323 0x7faacff871ce 0x7faacff861f6 0x7faacff871ce 0x7faacff861f6 0x7faacff871ce 0x7faacff861f6 0x7faacff86323 0x7faacff871ce 0x7faacff861f6 0x7faacff871ce 0x7faacff872e2 0x7faacffa7960 0x7faacffa7b3f 0x7faacffbd484 0x7faacf1b3830 0x400649
```

BTW, will this kind of message means process slow down? It show each iteraction, but only show `Raising pool_size_limit_` at first iteraction.

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 1677080 get requests, put_count=1802207 evicted_count=128000 eviction_rate=0.071024 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.001728
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 1808091 get requests, put_count=1942982 evicted_count=138000 eviction_rate=0.0710248 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00173332
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 1897335 get requests, put_count=2042025 evicted_count=148000 eviction_rate=0.0724771 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.00175773
```

At first, I think PoolAllocator caused by limited GPU memory.
After check `nvidia-smi` with `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True`, I found the GPU memory usage is `5833MiB /  8110MiB` far away from not enough, right?

Follow this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774449/fully-convolutional-resnets-using-tf-slim-run-very-slow), I add `os.environ['TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE'] = '0'`, doesn't work:(

Comment: I suspect you have an op that runs on CPU (ie, maybe it doesn't have GPU implementation). A good implementation of resnet is in models repo (300 msec per step on cifar on TitanX) -- https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/resnet

Comment: Hi @YaroslavBulatov. Except Resnet I have other ops, mostly are `map_fn`. I just found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697301/tensorflow-map-fn-performance-and-memory-use), do you think `map_fn` could be the reason?

Comment: map_fn is pretty slow, perhaps 100x slower than an equivalent linear algebra op for large inputs

Comment: thanks, I think this is the problem. In my extra block I use 4 `map_fn`. slow speed and PoolAllocator are most likely caused by `map_fn`

Comment: I did some memory profiling of using tf.maximum on matrix vs using tf.map_fn(tf.maximum), and had to lower the datasize 100 times to get the equivalent results to finish in time. The memory usage was also worse -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/clipping-profile.ipynb

Comment: Umm... such a huge difference. Does tensorflow has any plan to improve it, or there is other alternation?

Comment: The situation is similar to Python or matlab -- using `for` loop, which is like `map_fn` is much slower than doing equivalent computation using optimized linear algebra. Maybe XLA will eventually make it possible to do such things at the same speed as CuDNN, but probably not too soon